# syntax error in ruby using && in multiple conditions

Tags: ruby

I'm baffled why I have a syntax error using '&&' when combining two conditions that should be true before the program can continue. I'm new to ruby and have not had a chance to actually code a complete program by myself.
I am just updating an old program and following through whatever code that is similar to what I need to update it with.

Here's my code:

```
def drug_dispensation_condition(charge)
  return true if ['250','251'].include? charge[:rev_code]
  return true if ['981262'].include? charge[:cdm_code]
  return true if ['300'].include? charge[:rev_code] && ['86580'].include? charge[:cdm_code]  #this line is inserted
  false
end
```

Here's my error message:

> syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting keyword_end
>   (syntaxerror) ...e] && ['86580'].include? charge[:cdm_code]

I added the 3rd "return true" clause to include the rev_code 300 and the cdm_code 86580.
I need both the rev_code 300 and the cdm_code 86580 to declare the statement as True, so I needed to add the "&&" in between them. It looked like it was expecting the "end" after "charge[:rev_code]" instead of the 2nd condition.

Is there any other way of coding this to avoid the syntax error?

Answer (score 2):

As it's a one-line statement, wrap the include? arguments in parenthesis:

```
return true if ['300'].include?(charge[:rev_code]) && ['86580'].include?(charge[:cdm_code])
```

I think you could make it a little bit more readable:

```
def drug_dispensation_condition(charge)
  if ['250', '251', '300'].include?(charge[:rev_code]) ||
     ['981262', '86580'].include?(charge[:cdm_code])
    return true
  end
  false
end
```

Comment: Another thing to consider is `return true` when evaluating a boolean condition is a waste. Just express the logic as-is, which is implicitly returned.

Comment: I do not want to put together all the codes since I only want it to be True if both the rev_code '300' and the cdm_code '86580' exist. That is why I coded them separately. The other codes are independent of my new codes. Can I still use the "&&" with adding the parens?

Comment: I tried it with the parenthesis on the (charge[:rev_code]) and the (charge[:cdm_code]). I got another syntax error, unexpected tLPAREN_ARG, expecting keyword_end (SyntaxError) ..._code]) && ['86580'].include? (charge[:cdm_code]). Just curious, is the space between the "include?" and the "(charge" make any difference?

Comment: Yes, it does. The line that I added: return true if ['300'].include? (charge[:rev_code]) && ['86580'].include? (charge[:cdm_code])